# laravel 5.2 facebook login with LaravelFacebookSdk

Tags: facebook, heroku, laravel-5

I have heroku app with facebook login using [LaravelFacebookSdk](https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk#getting-a-tokenmismatchexception-with-canvas-apps) which is working fine. I am trying to route another URL to facebook canvas where I am facing some issue

1) not getting authorize app token from facebook.

2) passing https route link so canvas mix content issues are resolved.

[login with facebook is working fine](http://hazzir.herokuapp.com/login)

[facebook canvas login is not working!](https://apps.facebook.com/hazzir-app/)

For solving issue

1) [app/Http/route.php](https://github.com/asimkh/apps/blob/hazzir/app/Http/routes.php)

```
 Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/canvas', [
'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@FBcanvas',
'https' => true]);
```

2) [app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php](https://github.com/asimkh/apps/blob/hazzir/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php)

```
public function FBcanvas(LaravelFacebookSdk $fb)
{
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes']; // optional
$FBloginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(env('FACEBOOK_RECALL_URL'), $permissions);
echo '<a href="' . $FBloginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook</a>';
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you didn't use Socialite for this? https://github.com/laravel/socialite

Comment: You may check my code I applied “Socialite” Facebook login which is also working fine as I understand Laravel 5 comes with support for Socialite which allows you to authenticate with OAuth 2.0 providers. Currently my issue is that i have a separate site with home-page->facebook-login which is working fine but i want to implement another “canvas route” so i can use same laravel structure or project to do “Facebook Canvas” by another route.